# Why my webpage shakes after adding google font link in my html head tag?

Tags: html, css, webfonts

I created a webpage in the Vs code. Then I choose a font from **google-font** and **embedded its link in the head tag** of HTML. Then **added font family in CSS**. It worked properly. As I was testing the webpage in a live sever extension. **I noticed whenever I write a single character in CSS, the page** **shakes a lot**. When I stop writing code, shaking stops. During shaking Font becomes bigger, smaller, darker e.t.c without reason although I did nothing abut font .what is the problem behind this? How to stop this shaking?

```css
body{
font-family: 'Girassol', cursive;
font-size:25px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Dropdown Menu design</title>
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Girassol&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="indexstyle.css" />
    <script src="try.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      The University was established as compensation for the annulment of the
      1905 Partition of Bengal. The partition had established East Bengal and
      Assam as a separate province, with Dhaka as its capital. However, the
      partition was abolished in 1911. In 1913, public opinion was solicited
      before the university scheme was given its final shape, and the Secretary
      of State approved it in December 1913.[1] The first vice-chancellor of the
      university was Philip Joseph Hartog, who had been academic registrar of
      the University of London for 17 years.[
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does the website shake or the editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your answer. I just solved my problem using a method. As I was using vs code. I set up an autosave option. The autosave delay option was set to 100 milliseconds. When I converted it to 1000 milliseconds, it worked without shaking the page.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because as you type your CSS, it becomes temporarily invalid until you finish the rule you're typing. Since you're using a live preview extension, while the CSS is invalid, the rules aren't applied, so you will see changes to your pages appearance.